# Discrepancy after upgrading to Xcode 4.5 from 4.4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

After upgrading to Xcode 4.5 from 4.4, I ran the apps that I had made in v 4.4. Although the app compiles correctly, I see the following message in Output section of Debug area:

`Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.`

Can somebody please tell me why do I see this message after upgrading? I went through some of the answers for similar question. But I have not found anything that tells me why I see this message after upgrading.

Thank you!

Edit 1:

Am I supposed to incorporate the code in AddDelegate.m. If yes, I did something similar while following a book.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TabBarController" owner:self options:nil] 
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That message most likely was there already when using Xcode 4.4 (in fact it got introduced with Xcode 4.0 (dont recall exactly). Just make sure your UIWindow instance has a rootViewController assigned within the app delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 3.x and below, you used to do this:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view]
```

Since iOS 4, the canonical way is to do this:

```
window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

If you do not need to support iOS 2.x/3.x, then you should upgrade your code to do the latter.

IIRC, the warning's existed since iOS 5. It depends on the iOS version you run on, not the Xcode version.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please suggest how can I share a code that I wrote in response to your answer?

Comment: thank you. I just inserted an edit. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 2):

If you have set up your view controller(s) programatically, then in your app delegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method try the following:

`[self.window setRootViewController: yourRootViewController];`

If you set up your view controller via XIB, then if set up correctly your root view controller should be set up by default! (Which probably is a MainWindow.xib file in your project)